# What to do with this Swift language compiling error on windows

Tags: ios, swift, windows, mobile

I'm trying to learn how to build an ios mobile app and decided to install swift for windows. After I downloading and installing the software. I tried to compile and run the sample Hello.swift to test it but this error shows up. What to do? Thanks in advance

p.s. I already redownload and reinstalled the SwiftForWindows

[image: Swift Error when compiling]

Comment: I would try typing `link --help` as suggested...

Comment: I tried typing but it is disabled.. where should I type --help?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / command / output / error messages as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I already figure out the solution to my problem. Just install the Visual studio 14 and check the C++ on the option of installing